# Angular pattern validation pre-compiled

Tags: angular

I have an input field with pattern validation:

```
<input  matInput  required type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"  pattern="^[^#][^ ]*">
```

Only string without space are valid.

Due to an import, some of my models has spaces within name property. When I open the edit page and the input has the string pre-loaded, the input is not marked "red" as invalid. I need to focus on the input, change something to trigger the validation.

Is there a way to trigger all validation so all the inputs (like required ones) will printed red?

Thanks.

Comment: what u want exactly

Comment: When I open the edit page, I want all the fields with validity to false due to inline validator (ex. required, pattern...) to be marked "red" like when you focus them. 
Now, the user doesn't know which fields are not valid and he needs to focus every field to see if it turned red.